# Redirecting form submission to another page issue

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, redirect

On my Wordpress site, I would like to redirect it to a page like: example.com/user after submitting the form.

```
:method:POST
:path:/dash/product/edit/
```

here is the beginning of the form:

```
<!--  Submission Form -->
<form method="post" action="" id="wcv-product-edit" class="wcv-form wcv-formvalidator">
```

and the end of the form:

```
<?php WCVendors_Pro_Product_Form::form_data( $object_id, $post_status ); ?>
            <?php WCVendors_Pro_Product_Form::save_button( $title ); ?>
```

I tried placing this inside of a form:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/user');
```

But this redirects whole page where the form is located without form submission to example.com/user. Form is located on this path: `/dash/product/edit/`. So when I request this path (where the form is located) it just redirects to example.com/user

Form controller:

```
public function process_submit() { 

        if ( ! isset( $_POST[ '_wcv-save_product' ] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ '_wcv-save_product' ], 'wcv-save_product' ) || !is_user_logged_in() ) { 
            return; 
        }

        $can_submit_live        = WC_Vendors::$pv_options->get_option( 'can_submit_live_products' ); 
        $current_post_status    = isset( $_POST[ 'post_status' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'post_status' ] : ''; 
        $can_edit_approved      = WC_Vendors::$pv_options->get_option( 'can_edit_approved_products' ); 
        $trusted_vendor         = ( get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_wcv_trusted_vendor', true ) == 'yes' ) ? true: false;
        $untrusted_vendor       = ( get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_wcv_untrusted_vendor', true ) == 'yes' ) ? true: false;

        if ( $trusted_vendor ) $can_submit_live = true; 
        if ( $untrusted_vendor ) $can_submit_live = false; 


        $text = array( 'notice' => '', 'type' => 'success' );
```

How can I redirect it to `example.com/user` only after successfully submitting the form?

Answer (score 1):

You would need some kind of hook that give the status of the form and bind that to the redirection to act on the hook. Like making the redirection to be a function and you call that function when the form get submitted properly. There're third party plugin's like [Gravity From](http://www.gravityforms.com/) that can do this for you. Its up to you if you want a paid service like this.

```html
public function process_submit() { 

  if ( ! isset( $_POST[ '_wcv-save_product' ] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ '_wcv-save_product' ], 'wcv-save_product' ) || !is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    return; 
  }

  $can_submit_live        = WC_Vendors::$pv_options->get_option( 'can_submit_live_products' ); 
  $current_post_status    = isset( $_POST[ 'post_status' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'post_status' ] : ''; 
  $can_edit_approved      = WC_Vendors::$pv_options->get_option( 'can_edit_approved_products' ); 
  $trusted_vendor         = ( get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_wcv_trusted_vendor', true ) == 'yes' ) ? true: false;
  $untrusted_vendor       = ( get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_wcv_untrusted_vendor', true ) == 'yes' ) ? true: false;

  if ( $trusted_vendor ) {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/user');
  }else {
    # code...
  }


  $text = array( 'notice' => '', 'type' => 'success' );
}
```

```html
public function process_submit() { 

    if ( ! isset( $_POST[ '_wcv-save_product' ] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ '_wcv-save_product' ], 'wcv-save_product' ) || !is_user_logged_in() ) { 
      return; 
    }

    $can_submit_live        = WC_Vendors::$pv_options->get_option( 'can_submit_live_products' ); 
    $current_post_status    = isset( $_POST[ 'post_status' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'post_status' ] : ''; 
    $can_edit_approved      = WC_Vendors::$pv_options->get_option( 'can_edit_approved_products' ); 
    $trusted_vendor         = ( get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_wcv_trusted_vendor', true ) == 'yes' ) ? true: false;
    $untrusted_vendor       = ( get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_wcv_untrusted_vendor', true ) == 'yes' ) ? true: false;

    if ( $trusted_vendor ) $can_submit_live = true; 
    if ( $untrusted_vendor ) $can_submit_live = false; 

    if ($can_submit_live) {
      header('Location: http://www.example.com/user');
    }else {
      # code...
    }
    
    $text = array( 'notice' => '', 'type' => 'success' );
}
```

Comment: I would use the plugin but I have to use the form which is part of the plugin  :/

Comment: Since you're writing the form and the validation yourself; do you get validation fail or success result? If you do you can bind the `header('Location: http://www.example.com/user');` to that with a `if statement`. The redirection happen for no reason because its a standalone function and nothing to interrupt the default flow like if query

Comment: Hi, edited my question and added form controller with if statements on submit button. Please check it out.

Comment: Ok what are you doing with the data that comes from the form  as in are you adding the data in to a database or sending an email? and what's `$can_submit_live` purpose?

Comment: It goes to a database. And purpose of that is related to approved/unapproved user. If it's approved user (trusted_vendor) then it can submit a form.

Comment: So couldn't you use something like this? `if ( $trusted_vendor ) { header('Location: http://www.example.com/user'); } else { /*something here*/ }`

Comment: Or `if ( $can_submit_live) { header('Location: http://www.example.com/user'); } else { /*something here*/ }`

Comment: Thank you! But where should I place it?

Comment: I have created two snippets above for each possibility. See if they work for you.

Comment: I've tried both I'm getting an error "unexpected }"

Comment: It might be because I've closed the function at the bottom of the snippet. Your sample snippet did't have that try removing the `}` at the very bottom of my snippets. You should also get a line number for where the error occurred; if you have something like `}}` that near there, just remove one `}` tag.

Comment: not working unfortunately :/ it just stays on the same page.. but thank you!

Comment: How are you walling the function? What's the trigger?

Comment: Not sure since it's a Wordpress plugin.. I posted the whole submission controller here, so you can see what's going on: https://hastebin.com/epiqisotik.php

Comment: On line 70 you will see that at the moment when product is successfully submitted it shows a notice "Product Added.

Comment: If its a plugin its a different ball game; you probably don't even have access to how it authenticate; but you will have to override the default plugin validation by rewriting the whole thing. But on your Wordpress dashboard, do you have a from option?